# Java - make a library and import optional

Tags: java, jar, import, code-organization

I have a library that I'm using in an Java application - it's important for certain functionality, but it's optional.  Meaning that if the JAR file is not there, the program continues on without issue.  I'd like to open source my program, but I can not include this library, which is necessary to compile the source code as I have numerous import statements to use the API.  I don't want to maintain two code sets.  What is the best way to remove the physical jar file from open source release, but still maintain the code to support it where other people could still compile it?

Comment: I found this example helpful in implementing the interface.  http://www.janeve.me/articles/dynamic-loading-using-java-reflection-and-properties

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the typical approach taken is to define the wrapper API (i.e. interfaces) and include those interfaces in the open sourced code, and then provide configuration options where one can specify class names of classes that implement certain interfaces.

You will import API interfaces instead of importing classes directly into your open sourced code. This way, you are open sourcing the API but not the implementation of the parts that you do not want to open source or you cannot open source.

There are many examples, but take a look at JDBC API (interfaces) and JDBC drivers (implementation classes) for starters.

Answer (score 4):

There's probably a number of ways to fix this, here's a couple I can think of:

- If you have only a couple of methods you need to invoke in the 3rd party library, you could use reflection to invoke those methods. It creates really verbose code, that is hard to read though.
- If you don't have too much of the API in the 3rd party library you use, you could also create a separate JAR file, containing just a non-functional shell of the classes in the library (just types with the same names and methods with the same signatures). You can then use this JAR to distribute and compile against. At run-time you'd replace it with the real JAR if available.
- The most common way is probably to just create a wrapper API in a separate module/project for the code that is dependent on the 3rd party library, and possibly distribute a pre-built JAR. This might go against your wish to not maintain two code sets, but may prove to be the best and less painful solution in the long run.

Answer (score 3):

I was pretty much typing the same thing as smallworld with one addition. If this API were necessary you can use a project build tool like Maven to handle the dependencies on you project. If someone checks it out from source control with the pom they can download the dependencies for themselves and you don't have to include them in a source repo.